# How to filter lines by counting occurences of a char in AWK or bash?

Tags: linux, shell, sed, awk

The input is like this:

```
CNNCC
NCNCN
NNNCC
CCNNN
CCCCN
```

The output should be like this:

```
CNNCC
CCCCN
```

which means, if there're **more than 3 occurences of `N`, that line would be filtered out**, otherwise it's kept. (In my work, I need to filter out 100000 lines with more than **500** N so performance might be important)

I know how to filter by consecutive `N` in awk, but I don't know how to calculate inconsecutive ones..

Does anyone have ideas about this? Solutions in `shell`  is also ok.

**Among all the answers, I think this one might be the simpest:**

```
awk -FN 'NF<=3'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
awk -FN -vcount=3 'NF<=count'
```

or, for older `awk` which does not support the `-v` option,

```
awk -FN 'NF<=count' count=3
```

The command uses the target char as the field separator and the maximum allowed occurence as `count`. By comparing the resulting number of fields against `count` we can selectively print lines that meet our criteria.

The intention of the statement is not immediately obvious and therefore less readable. It does however has the advantage of having the char and `count` parametrised and can therefore be easily reused for different settings.

Admittedly, this would not be very efficient for large numbers of `count`. Setting the maximum number of fields to `count+1` would overcome this performance issue, unfortunately the `-mf` option is ignored by gawk.

Comment: This one work! But only work for `gawk` It shows `/usr/bin/awk: invalid -v option` on my MACOS

Comment: @Firegun If you're happy to hardcode the `count`, try `awk -F'N' 'NF<=3{print}'`

Comment: @Firegun I your case where you have a large number of N's and you're using `awk` rather than `gawk` do try setting the `-mf` options as well (see last paragraph), e.g. `awk -F'N' -mf 501 'NF<=500{print}'`

Comment: Rather than using `-v`, you can also do: `awk -FN 'NF<=count' count=3`.  (`{print}` is redundant.)

Comment: @WilliamPursell Many thanks. That's so much better. Answer updated.

Comment: If your awk doesn't support -v then get a new awk as that option is supported by all modern awks, not just GNU awk, and any awk that doesn't support that will be missing other functionality too. Also, -v is usually the right way to set variables as that sets them for the BEGIN section too, whereas using var=val in the arg list only sets them after BEGIN. Nice solution +1!

Comment: @EdMorton good point. I've reincluded the version with `-v` just so readers have a choice.

Comment: great, but I suggest you don't name the command "gawk" as that makes it sound like it's gawk-specific when it isn't: -v will work with all modern awks including gawk, nawk, tawk, /usr/xpg4/bin/awk, etc.

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/(.*N){3}/d' file
```

or

```
sed 's/N/&/3;T;d' file
```

Answer (score 2):

A `sed` solution using the same regular expression:

```
% sed '/N.*N.*N/d'
```

`d` deletes every line that *anywhere* has three or more `N` characters.

**Example:**

```
% sed '/N.*N.*N/d' <<EOF
`heredoc> CNNCC
`heredoc> NCNCN
`heredoc> NNNCC
`heredoc> CCNNN
`heredoc> CCCCN
`heredoc> EOF
CNNCC
CCCCN
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `gsub` to count:

```
awk 'gsub(/N/,"N") < 3' file.txt
```

Results:

```
CNNCC
CCCCN
```

Comment: But this would `gsub` *every* `N`. Isn't it enough to stop matching after the third `N`?

Answer (score 2):

No love for `grep`?

```
count=3
egrep -v "(.*N){$count}" file
```

---

More info:

`-v` inverts match, so this find lines that does not contain 3 N's (if the line has more than 3 N's, it contains 3 N's).

`egrep` is equivalent to `grep -E` which uses extended regexp (ERE), used here so that `( )` and `{ }` don't have to be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

Perl one-liner

```
perl -ne 'print if tr/N/N/ < 3'
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
gawk '/N.*N.*N/ { next; } { print; }'
```

Comment: @Firegun The number of lines is not relevant. The regular expression implementation of `gawk` should be efficient enough to match even lines with 500+ characters.